# If the Electoral Count Act is repealed, would Pence have the power to throw out states' results?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, congress, constitution, electoral-college

I have just found that [another lawsuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-election_lawsuits_related_to_the_2020_United_States_presidential_election#Gohmert_et_al._v._Pence) have been filed in Texas, aimed at overturning the presidential election result and seeking for the courts to invalidate the Electoral Count Act as unconstitutional.

My question: **Assuming that the judge rules on the eve of counting the electoral votes in Congress that the law is unconstitutional, would this give the president of the Senate (Mike Pence) the power to throw out the votes of some electoral slates from contested states and replace them with votes of alternate slates which claim to be appointed by the state legislatures?** The constitution requires him to open the certificates, but does not say which certificates are to be opened if there are several of them.

This is not a duplicate of a previous question, because the possibility of invalidation of the Electoral Count Act by a court decision was not considered before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can state legislatures decide to appoint a different set of delegates to those determined by the vote?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/59768/can-state-legislatures-decide-to-appoint-a-different-set-of-delegates-to-those-d)

Comment: @JoeC No it does not answer my question, as it assumes the validity of the Electoral Count Act, whereas my question asks about hypothetical case of this law to be invalidated by a court decision.

Comment: The answer does cover your scenario about rejecting and resolving disputes between slates of electors though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What procedures are in place to stop a U.S. Vice President from ignoring electors?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61206/what-procedures-are-in-place-to-stop-a-u-s-vice-president-from-ignoring-elector)

Comment: @RickSmithr This is much closer to my question, but the answer again assumes the procedure described in ECA. My question: what can be the procedure if the ECA is ruled to be unconstitutional.

Comment: Just a little point not worth a whole answer; constitutionality isn't binary.  SCOTUS can invalidate all of the ECA, none of the ECA, or anywhere in-between.

Comment: @Ryan_L This is not SCOTUS but a Texas federal Court. Is not its ruling obligatory for Mr. Pence (especially if he agrees)?

Comment: @user it would be obligatory.  I'm saying the ruling isn't necessarily black-and-white.  They could partially invalidate the ECA, but keep it functionally intact.

Comment: Per today's news (1/2/21), that Texas court threw out the lawsuit, so the question becomes moot.

Comment: @jamesqf the ruling is subject to appeal, and apparently the government argued that the complaint should have been filed against congress, so maybe someone will try that at some point.

Comment: @phoog Appeals court dismisses Gohmert's election suit against Pence

Comment: Yes, but @phoog's other point otherwise stands. The 5th circuit said "We express no view on the underlying merits or on what putative party, if any, might have standing."

Comment: @Fizz I do not think the remaining time is sufficient for another lawsuit.

Comment: As the (lower) court said, suing before Pence (or Congress) does anything in terms of counting is pointless. They do have ~4 years to sue thereafter. (Chances of those suits succeeding aren't anything good of course.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Assume that the judge rules on the eve of counting the electoral votes in Congress that the law is unconstitutional (I know this sounds crazy). Does it really gives the president of Senate (M. Pence) the power to throw out the votes of some electoral slates from contested states and replace them with votes of alternate slates which claim to be appointed by the state legislatures?

Well, Gohmert is specifically asking the court to declare *both* things, I.E. that the law is unconstitutional AND that Pence can pick and chose which votes to count. See page 25 of the [complaint](https://www.democracydocket.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/45/2020/12/Gohmert-v-Pence.pdf), in the Prayer for Relief section:

> C. Declares that Vice-President Pence, in his capacity as President of Senate and Presiding Officer of the January 6, 2021 Joint Session of Congress,is subject solely to the requirements of the Twelfth Amendment and may exercise the exclusive authority and sole discretion in determining which electoral votes to count for a given State
>
> D. Enjoins reliance on any provisions of the Electoral Count Act that would limit Defendant’sexclusive authority and his sole discretion to determine which of two or more competing slates of electors’ votes are to be counted for President;
>
> E. Declares that, with respect to competing slates of electors from the State of Arizona or other Contested States, or with respect to objection to any single slate of electors, the Twelfth Amendment contains the exclusive dispute resolution mechanisms, namely, that (i) Vice-President Pence determines which slate of electors’ votes shall be counted, or if none be counted, for that State

So yeah, Gohmert's suit is specifically trying to get a ruling that Pence can choose which votes to keep and which to toss.

Comment: Do I correctly understand that if the judge agrees to all of this say at 12:50 on 6.01.2021 Mr. Pence has to follow the ruling (especially if he has nothing against it)?

Comment: @user one suspects the answer is currently undefined, but also that it would be _instantly_ appealed. Normally orders that are appealed are ineffective until the appeal is somehow disposed of, so I _think_ (and as I say, the answer is really "who knows?") that the likeliest outcome in that scenario is that the order has no effect. This is moot though; of all the post-election lawsuits, this one is literally the craziest. And I include in that the Sydney Powell craziness

Comment: But who will appeal, if the defendant (M.Pence) accepts the decision?

Comment: @user An [intervenor-defendant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervention_(law)), would be my expectation. Likely the Democratic part or some NGO. Note that that requires they intervene before judgement, so that's an action I'd expect to happen fairly soon.

Comment: Thank you. The reference you gave says that a party can intervene only before the final judgement.  Let us see if there will be such timely intervention.

Comment: As the reference in the link is dead I give it here: Rule 60 - Intervenor's Pleadings

Any party may intervene by filing a pleading, subject to being stricken out by the court for sufficient cause on the motion of any party.

Tex. R. Civ. P. 60

Comment: @user: since the lawsuit doesn't name the Senate as a defendant, it would not bind any other senator from objecting to Pence in Congress, even if Pence himself were to claim he's bound by some lawsuit injunction. There's no real need for anyone to intervene in that lawsuit, except to save Pence from a potential (personal) embarrassment.

Comment: @Fizz but in the event that the Judge in this case weirdly made the ruling that Pence had sole authority to decide which votes to count, what power over that process would a Senator's objection have?

Comment: @Fizz I agree with Dan. The Constitution does not specify who counts the votes. The votes simply "are counted". If there is no law, then some new rules shall be installed. And if there are no rules in time, the House elects the President, and GOP has there the required  27 votes majority.

Comment: The same power that prevents SCOTUS (or any judge) from suddenly claiming they can appoint the POTUS themselves, because that's how they suddenly decided to interpret the constitution after a having a good cup of coffee this morning. Keep in mind that there's nothing in the Constitution that says (even) SCOTUS (let alone some lower federal judge) is the ultimate interpreter of the Constitution, in all aspects.

Comment: That view is merely tolerated/accepted by other branches of government, because it hasn't resulted in any totally crazy judicial decisions insofar, e.g. SCOTUS has deemed some matters political and thus not justicable. Should a court decide everything is justiciable and thus they can basically rule the country from the bench in all aspects, the legislature could overrule them, setting up a real constitutional crisis, but whose outcome is frankly easy to predict. No judge has been able to stage a "legal" coup by themselves... in any country.

Comment: @Fuzz I understand. But I can imagine a crazy judge who may consider himself as the "ultimate interpreter of the Constitution" and therfore wonder how to prevent this from happening. Unfortunately it seems that there are enough crazy people also in the WH and the Congress.

Comment: @Fizz well sure; that's what I mean by "I expect the answer is actually 'undefined'". I kinda disagree that there's no need for anyone to intervene in the lawsuit though; as unlikely as it is that any judge will rule in Grohmert's favour (for the reasons you outlined), it makes it easier to argue that this particular judge's nonsense needs to be overruled if you've followed the rules up to that point yourself (I.E. in the highly unlikely event the judge goes rogue, an intervenor-defendant's appeal is obviously legit whereas a political opponent's objection will be more easily muddied)

Comment: The federal courts themselves [have](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1071259?seq=1) deemed non-justiciable "resolution of disputes between parties who are not truly adverse". Suing Pence in order to *increase* his powers is basically laughable. They might as well sue Trump at SCOTUS and ask the latter to appoint him president.

Comment: [It looks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervention_(law)#United_States) like the right to intervene is at the discretion of the judge (in most cases) anyway. A putative "dictator judge" can simply deny the motion. It's unclear to me if denied motions to intervene can be appealed anywhere, in themselves. FWTW https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/59705/can-denied-motions-to-intervene-be-appealed-in-themselves

Comment: @user because apparently the fathers of the constitution considered it obvious that different people counting the same objects necessarily arrive at the same result.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Obviously their assumption that there can be no more than one slate of electors from a state was false.

Comment: @user, FYI - an _actual_ Arizona elector intervened in this case yesterday, and on the same day Pence's lawyers filed a motion asking for the case to be dismissed for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @DanScally Thank you for info. I have checked. He is an actual *Colorado* elector. Let see whether he will be admitted as an intervenor (in the case that the lawsuit is not simply dismissed).

Comment: @DanScally It is dismissed.

Comment: @user: No, there can be, and IS, only one legal set of electors, and electoral votes, from any state: the ones selected in the election and transmitted "sealed to the seat of the government of the United States, directed to the President of the Senate" (12th Amendment).  Unfortunately Trump has found some patsies to go along with his delusion that he's not a loser, but that can't change the facts.

Answer (score 5):

As I said in some comments, suing Pence in this case was obviously silly, as Pence attorneys themselves actually [argued](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2021/1/2/us-judge-dismisses-lawmaker-case-against-pence-over-vote-count) (and the suit was dismissed for lack of standing):

> A Justice Department lawyer representing Pence on Thursday urged [judge] Kernodle to dismiss the lawsuit saying they had sued the wrong person as they raised “a host of weighty legal issues about the manner in which the electoral votes for president are to be counted”. “The Senate and the House, not the Vice President, have legal interests that are sufficiently adverse to plaintiffs to ground a case or controversy,” Pence’s filing said.

[In general](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1071259), the federal courts have deemed non-justiciable "resolution of disputes between parties who are not truly adverse".

---

As it was suggested by Dan Scally in comments might happen, there was an (unopposed) [motion to intervene](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.txed.203073/gov.uscourts.txed.203073.25.0.pdf) in the suit... but it was from Trump's electors from Michigan. There was actually one very late [motion](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.txed.203073/gov.uscourts.txed.203073.36.0.pdf) to intervene from a Biden elector from Colorado. I think there wasn't even any ruling on this motion before the lawsuit was dismissed. (Well, it was denied as moot, without specific reference to it, in the final judgment that dismissed the case [and thus all pending motions].)

Note that the plaintiffs filed a notice that they are appealing to the 5th circuit, so this isn't quite over yet.

---

As [explained](https://www.politico.com/f/?id=00000176-bb0e-d162-a7ff-fb0e44780000) in Politico, the dismissal was mainly due to the uncertanty of the alleged injury:

> A judge said Rep. Louie Gohmert lacked standing under a 1997 Supreme Court ruling that said individual lawmakers did not have standing to challenge a line-item veto law Congress passed a year earlier.
>
> “Congressman Gohmert’s alleged injury requires a series of hypothetical—but by no means certain—events,” the judge wrote in his 13-page ruling issued Friday evening. “Plaintiffs presuppose what the Vice President will do on January 6, which electoral votes the Vice President will count or reject from contested states, whether a Representative and a Senator will object under Section 15 of the Electoral Count Act, how each member of the House and Senate will vote on any such objections, and how each state delegation in the House would potentially vote under the Twelfth Amendment absent a majority electoral vote.”
>
> “All that makes Congressman Gohmert’s alleged injury far too uncertain to support standing under” the Constitution, Kernodle added.

Although they are filing an appeal, the plaintiffs don't seem too convinced it could succeed...

> "Bottom line is, the court is saying, ‘we’re not going to touch this, you have no remedy,’" Gohmert said. "Basically, in effect, the ruling would be that you’ve got to go to the streets and be as violent as antifa and BLM."

The judgement actually detailed the issue of standing in re judicial intervention
in the actions of other branches of government, citing from the [*Raines v. Byrd*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raines_v._Byrd) extensively on that basically to show that
this is a strict standard. And after a couple of pages of that, it says:

> [Gohmert] asserts that under the Electoral Count Act, “he will not be able
> to vote as a *Congressional Representative* in accordance with the Twelfth
> Amendment.” Docket No. 2 at 4 (emphasis added). Because Congressman Gohmert
> is asserting an injury in his role as a Member of Congress rather than as an individual voter, *Raines* controls. [...]
>
> Congressman Gohmert’s alleged injury is “a type of
> institutional injury (the diminution of legislative power), which necessarily damages
> all Members of Congress.” Id. Under these circumstances, the Supreme Court held
> in Raines, a Member of Congress does not have “a sufficient ‘personal stake’” in the
> dispute and lacks “a sufficiently concrete injury to have established Article III
> standing.” Id. at 830.

The judgement then also cited [Clapper v. Amnesty International USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clapper_v._Amnesty_International_USA)
 that the scenario laid out by Gohmert is too speculative to clear that bar:

> Congressman Gohmert’s alleged injury requires a series of
> hypothetical—but by no means certain—events. Plaintiffs presuppose what the Vice
> President will do on January 6, which electoral votes the Vice President will count or
> reject from contested states, whether a Representative and a Senator will object
> under Section 15 of the Electoral Count Act, how each member of the House and
> Senate will vote on any such objections, and how each state delegation in the House
> would potentially vote under the Twelfth Amendment absent a majority electoral
> vote. All that makes Congressman Gohmert’s alleged injury far too uncertain to
> support standing under Article III. Id. at 414 (“We decline to abandon our usual
> reluctance to endorse standing theories that rest on speculation about the decisions
> of independent actors.”).

So basically it was a "double whammy" against Gohmert's claim (no personal standing (*Raines*) and scenario too speculative (*Clapper*)).

Trump electors' standing was basically denied because they didn't explicitly ask for Pence to *count their votes as a remedy*, only that he'd be given the latitude to do so. So again, they were speculating on his behavior.
That still leaves open that they can/may sue Pence after he does his thing (and if the lawsuit explicitly asks for Pence to act differently). Of some interest here, something like that did happen with *Raines*, as it was followed by
[Clinton v. City of New York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinton_v._City_of_New_York). In contrast to *Clinton* though, it would be much more difficult to show that Pence acts/acted illegally or unconstitutionally if he decides to open/"count" only Biden's electors' submission from Arizona. Which is basically (probably) why this Gohmert lawsuit was brought in this form that it was.